# css image autoresize not working

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to get 2 columns :

1. one div called words and
2. other ul called snaps which has li of images

currently when i resize the images instead of resizing it just moves to next row...how do i get them to resize based on screen width

below is the example

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="subfooter">
    <div class="words">
        this is test messgae
        </div>

        <ul class="snaps">
        <li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR6HIp-1dv221Es0Hk1E9OuQMzcavdw51paj4T0-zrZfxKgXmUXfA"/></li>
        <li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR6HIp-1dv221Es0Hk1E9OuQMzcavdw51paj4T0-zrZfxKgXmUXfA" /></li> 

        <li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR6HIp-1dv221Es0Hk1E9OuQMzcavdw51paj4T0-zrZfxKgXmUXfA"/></li>

        <li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR6HIp-1dv221Es0Hk1E9OuQMzcavdw51paj4T0-zrZfxKgXmUXfA" /></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

 </div>
```

below is the working example
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/npg5s/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/npg5s/7/)**

You need to specify the width of `<li>` elements and then you can use `width:100%; height:auto;` on the images so they resize according to the width of `<li>` elements.

CSS :

```
.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.subfooter {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #99CC66;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.words {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #996633;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.snaps li {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:50%;
}
.snaps li img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.snaps {
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: but all four don't come in a single row anytime how do i get tht

Comment: somewhat...as now its coming belows the words div...i wantittobe next to words div so its 2 columns instead of 1 column so that when i resize to mediascreen of tmobilethen itshould be 1 column as its now

Comment: after a certain width snaps divjumps below instead of resizing the screen is still bigger than tabletscreen y is the image not resizing...especiialy since both words and snaps div are in %

Comment: yes...hey once screen becomes smaller and words and snaps div line up in single column can we get them to occupy 100% of the width...right now asu see the wordsdiv(brown) continues tooccupy only45% even after they align in single column

Answer (score 0):

This is because the images has a fixed with, use percentages instead of setting them to be 200px

This is what i did:

```
.snaps li {
width: 50%;
float: left;
display: block;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
}

.snaps li img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following instead of width 200:

```
.snaps li img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've updated you fiddle.

```
.words {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    background-color: #996633;

}
.snaps {
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.snaps li img {
    width:23%;
    float:left;
    margin:1%;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/npg5s/8/)**

Comment: images alignas a column i want them to be as row andto adjust inside the snaps div